# Delphi memory leak in BTMemoryModule

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

testing for memory leaks with madhi's madExcept, and the unit [BTMemoryModule](http://pastebin.com/2d9gTbiC) to load DLLs straight to ram from a resource, it's reporting leaks here:

How could this be fixed?

```
    type: VirtualAlloc  
    address: $71d1000  
    size: 177664  
    access rights: ./.

    main thread ($1134):  
    671cd432 madExcept32.dll madExceptDbg 2511 VirtualAllocCallback  
    006a8694 x.exe BTMemoryModule 196 CopySections  
    006a8cee x.exe BTMemoryModule 418 BTMemoryLoadLibary

    type: VirtualAlloc  
    address: $71d0000  
    size: 262144  
    access rights: ./.

    main thread ($1134):  
    671cd432 madExcept32.dll madExceptDbg 2511 VirtualAllocCallback  
    006a8ca4 x.exe BTMemoryModule 409 BTMemoryLoadLibary

    type: VirtualAlloc  
    address: $71d0000  
    size: 262144  
    access rights: ./.

    main thread ($1134):  
    671cd432 madExcept32.dll madExceptDbg 2511 VirtualAllocCallback  
    006a8c3f x.exe BTMemoryModule 396 BTMemoryLoadLibary
```

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, BTMemoryModule;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
  public
  end;

Const UnrarLibDLL = 'UNRARDLL';

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  rStream: TResourceStream;
  mp_MemoryModule: PBTMemoryModule;
  mp_DllData: Pointer;
  m_DllDataSize: Integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if m_DllDataSize > 0 then FreeMemory( mp_DllData );
  if mp_MemoryModule <> nil then BTMemoryFreeLibrary( mp_MemoryModule );
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  rStream := TResourceStream.Create( HInstance, UnrarLibDLL, RT_RCDATA );
  try
    m_DllDataSize := rStream.Size;
    mp_DllData    := GetMemory( m_DllDataSize );
    rStream.Read( mp_DllData^, m_DllDataSize );
  finally
    rStream.Free;
  end;

  mp_MemoryModule := BTMemoryLoadLibary( mp_DllData, m_DllDataSize );
end;

end.
```

How to reproduce:

- Enable madExcept with the option to report resource leaks
- Add any DLL in the project resources (in my case unrar.dll) with RCDATA name UNRARDLL
- Start and close the app

Comment: How sure are you that the library itself is leaking? Can we see your code that uses it?

Comment: The leak report tells you where the memory was allocated you can see the call that allocates the memory. Why is it not deallocated?

Comment: Added some basic source to reproduce the issue. It's suposedly deallocate on BTMemoryFreeLibrary.

Comment: Freeware from here http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm but it's just an example, you can load any DLL to test this issue, don't even need to assign the exports.

Comment: The dll is in the Downloads section of the official Winrar website, inside a packed file with "license.txt" that says "The unrar.dll library is freeware." "2. The unrar.dll library may be used in any software to handle RAR archives without limitations free of charge.". How exactly is that not freeware?

Comment: I read this http://www.win-rar.com/winrarlicense.html?&L=0 but maybe it does have an exception for that dll

Comment: The dll is a separate download labeled "UnRAR dynamic library for Windows software developers."

Comment: *The leak report tells you where the memory was allocated you can see the call that allocates the memory. Why is it not deallocated?* I mean, in the library, which line of code has the leaked allocation.

Comment: There are various (after BTMemoryModule in the leak report I pasted): 196, 396, 409, 418

Comment: `OnClose` is wrong. You mean `OnDestroy`. That won't impact this. Also, `FreeMemory` should be called after `BTMemoryFreeLibrary`.

Comment: It's not clear whether or not there is a leak here. Why do you care? Do you need to load and unload the DLL a lot? Also, loading DLLs from memory is an unsupported hack. You get what you deserve to be brutally frank. Use `LoadLibrary` and you won't have leaks.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the [latest version](https://code.google.com/p/memorymodule/source/browse/trunk/BTMemoryModule/BTMemoryModule.pas?r=2). Don't know if it would make a difference.

Comment: Tried newer ones, same happens.

Answer (score 1):

Another company made a working DLL loader that does NOT leak memory. The sources are in IPWCore.pas in IPWork's Internet (Components) Delphi Edition that comes with all versions of Delphi.

```
interface
uses IPWcore;
...
type
  _FunctionDLL = function: integer; stdcall;

var
  pEntryPoint: Pointer;
  pBaseAddress: Pointer;
  FunctionDLL: _FunctionDLL;

implementation

procedure TYourForm.FormCreate;
var
  hResInfo: HRSRC;
  hResData: HGLOBAL;
  pResData: Pointer;
begin
  hResInfo := FindResource(HInstance, 'EMVDLL', RT_RCDATA);
  hResData := LoadResource(HInstance, hResInfo);
  if hResData = 0 then
    exit;
  pResData := LockResource(hResData);
  if pResData = nil then
    exit;
  
  pBaseAddress := IPWorksLoadDRU(pResData, pEntryPoint);
  @FunctionDLL := IPWorksFindFunc(pBaseAddress, 'Function');
  ...
end;

procedure TYourForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IPWorksFreeDRU(pBaseAddress, pEntryPoint);
  pBaseAddress := nil;
  pEntryPoint := nil;
end;
```